Defining the current in curved space using differential forms
I am studying a static and axially symmetric field configuration in curved spacetime, with the metric parametrized as
\begin{equation}
ds^2=-N^2dt^2+h_{ik}\,dx^i dx^k=-N^2dt^2 + e^{2K}\left(dr^2+r^2d\theta^2\right) + e^{2S}\sin^2\theta\,d\varphi^2.
\end{equation}
The Maxwell's equations in curved space read
\begin{equation}
\nabla_\nu F^{\mu\nu} = 4\pi J^\mu,
\end{equation}
which can be translated in the differential form language as
\begin{equation}
d\star F=4\pi\star J,
\end{equation}
where $F$ is the field strength 2-form, $J$ is the current 1-form and $\star$ denotes the Hodge dual operator in spacetime. For my specific problem, the current density has only a azimuthal component, $J=J_\varphi\,d\varphi$, and my collaborator has derived the following expression for the current in the upper half-space $r\in[0,+\infty]$, $\vartheta\in[0,\pi/2]$ :
\begin{equation}
I_{+}=\int_0^{\infty}{dr\int_0^{\pi/2}{d\theta\sqrt{-g}\,J^\varphi}}.
\end{equation}
I just want to make sure that I understand correctly the derivation of this expression.
First, he rewrites the Maxwell's equations in terms of the "spatial" Hodge dual $\star_s$ :
\begin{equation}
d(N\star_s F)=4\pi N\star_s J.
\end{equation}
Here I understand that the 4-dimensional Hodge dual contains the factor $\sqrt{-g}$ in front of the antisymmetric Levi-Civita symbol, $\star\sim\sqrt{-g}\,\epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$, whereas the spacelike Hodge dual contains only the determinant of the 3-metric $h$ : $\star_s\sim\sqrt{h}\,\epsilon_{ijk}$. This yields $d\star F=4\pi\star J\;\Rightarrow\;d(N\star_s F)=4\pi N\star_s J$. Is my reasonning correct? I am struggling to prove this step rigorously, but I think that this is possible only for the static case considered here.
Second, he integrates the "spatial" Maxwell's equation over a 2-surface $\Sigma$ and use Stoke's theorem to obtain,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\partial\Sigma}{N\star_s F}=\int_\Sigma{N\star_s J}\equiv I.
\end{equation}
The left-hand side being the circulation of the magnetic field over the contour $\partial\Sigma$, the right-hand side defines is the current. Now, computing the Hodge dual $\star_s J$ yields,
\begin{equation}
\star_s J = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{h}\,\epsilon_{ijk}J^i\,dx^j\wedge dx^k=\sqrt{h}\,J^\varphi\,dr\wedge d\theta.
\end{equation}
And finally, choosing $\Sigma=[0,\infty]\times[0,\pi/2]$, we obtain the desired expression:
\begin{equation}
I_{+} = \int_\Sigma{\sqrt{-g}\,J^\varphi\,dr\wedge d\theta}=\int_0^\infty{dr\int_0^{\pi/2}{d\theta\sqrt{-g}\,J^\varphi}}.
\end{equation}
Again, is everything correct in my derivation? Also, I would like to know how all of this generalize in a non-static but stationary spacetime for which $g_{t\varphi}\neq 0$. In this case, I am not even sure that we can switch from $\star$ to $\star_s$ in Maxwell's equation. But then $\star J$ is a 3-form, so how to integrate it over a 2-surface ? May be both sides of Maxwell's can be factorized by $\wedge dt$ so we can restrict to a "spatial" 2-form as it was the case here.

Usually $J$ is not a one-form but a vector field. Note that the index of $J^\mu$ is in superscript. If you want to integrate the current against some hypersurface $\Sigma$ you take the volume form $\omega \in \Omega^{d}(\mathcal M)$ and plug in the vector field to get a $d-1$-form
$$
\alpha = \iota_{J} \omega = \omega (J, \dots)
$$
After dealing with questions of orientation, you can integrate
$$\int_\Sigma \alpha$$.
Sometimes $\alpha$ is also called the current. Note, that it is not a one-form but a $d-1$-form.

I know that $J$ is usually a vector field. But since we have a metric, one can directly obtain a 1-form out of it whose components are $J_\mu=g_{\mu\nu} J^\nu$. I am not sure to understand completely your answer. First when you say the dimension is $d$, do you refer to full spacetime dimension (4 in my case) or "spatial slices" dimension (which is 3 for me) ? If $d=4$ for you, then the volume form is $\omega=\sqrt{-g} dt\wedge dr\wedge d\theta\wedge d\varphi$. If I plug the current, I obtain a 3-form, which can be integrated over a 3-surface, but not over a 2-surface. Could you please clarify?

Sorry for keeping the dimension general. Yes in your case $d=4$.
